# Comparison of two strings and its references

Tags: java, string, object

On the one hand;

```
String first = "thing";

String second = "thing";

if(first == second)

System.out.print( "Same things" );    //this is printed
```

On the other hand;

```
String first = "thing";

String second = new String("thing");

if(first == second)
{
 System.out.print("Same things");
}
else
{
 System.out.print("Different things"); //This is printed
}
```

I know that " == " operator is using for the comparison of references of two objects, but in the first example, I compared the values of objects directly. I know this kind of comparison is inexact. But why do I get the message in first example? Is it an indicator that references are the same, or is it occured by a coincidence?

Comment: Why is this confusing? In the first example, `first` and `second` both point to `"thing"`, which is obviously the same string. In the second example, `second` points to a new `String` object that contains the text `"thing"`. When using `==`, the contents of the `String` are not considered, so the fact that both `String`s contain the text `"thing"` is irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strings of Same Value in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558285/strings-of-same-value-in-java)

Comment: There are same strings but in spite of creating different objects, it is returned true. But references should have been different. This is why I am confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in first example `String pool` was used - if you don't use `new` keyword - every new instance of String lands on that pool, and if String with same value is created - no new object is made - that one on pool is being used.

Comment: small addition: and if you use new keyword - normal object is created and kept where other objects - on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's how Java optimizes by caching strings created using this method:

```
String second = "thing";
```

And therefore makes them "equal".

When doing this:

```
String second = new String("thing");
```

You explicitly allocate a new string with those contents, which makes your `if` condition false.

Comment: It's not compiler, its java optimalizing

Answer (score 0):

```
String first = "thing";

String second = new String("thing");

if(first.equals(second))
{
 System.out.print("Same things");
}
else
{
 System.out.print("Different things"); //This is printed
}
```

This should be work.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, Java is assigning exactly the same object to first and second.

In the second example, Java is creating a new Object 'second' (which internally points to the first). So what you have are two string objects first and second, but second internally contains a reference to first.

See the documentation for the [String#intern()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29). From that:

> Returns a canonical representation for the string object. A pool of
>   strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String.
>
> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a
>   string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object)
>   method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this
>   String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String
>   object is returned.
>
> It follows that for any two strings s and t, s.intern() == t.intern()
>   is true if and only if s.equals(t) is true.
>
> All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are
>   interned. String literals are defined in §3.10.5 of the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/html/)

Answer (score 0):

In the first, `first` and `second` have same reference.

But in the second, they have different references.

With `==` you are actually comparing the values in the variables `first` and `second`, which are the references to the string objects. You are not comparing the objects themselves. Which would be done using the `equals` method.

Comment: Actually I don't care the equals() method, It has to be used. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @El3ctr0n1c4: "but in the first example, I compared the values of objects directly", sounds like your thinking that you are comparing the content of the objects there. So, I was just trying to make sure that you know by using `==` you are comparing the contents of the variables `first` and `second` instead of the contents of the objects they are referring to.

Comment: You're right, I was mistaken at that place. I try to improve my English :)

Answer (score 0):

string literals are [interned](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) you would also get the message with

```
String first = "thing";

String second = new String("thing");

if(first.intern() == second.intern())
{
 System.out.print("Same things"); //This is printed
}
else
{
 System.out.print("Different things");
}
```