# Java String comparision depending on object initialisation

Tags: java, string, equals

Following code:

```
    String a = new String("aaa");
    String a2 = new String("aaa");
    System.out.println(a == a2);

    String b = "bbb";
    String b2 = "bbb";
    System.out.println(b == b2);
```

Produces following output:

```
false
true
```

Why there is difference in output for comparision a==a2 and b==b2 depending from type of String creation ?

Comment: [What is the difference between "text" and new String("text")?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3052442)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you declare `a` and `a2` you explicitly create new (different) `String`s. The use of the constructor causes a copy to be made. Hence `==` fails as `a` and `a2` point to different values.

When you declare `b` and `b2`, `b2` can re-use the same string from the pool. Hence they actually point to the same value and `==` returns `true`.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558285/strings-of-same-value-in-java) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings) for a detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks ! Two years of experience and I didnt know that functionallitz about string :D Shame

Comment: No worries. That's was SO is for. Feel free to accept the answer :)